# How do I create a streamable and seekable MP4?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, mplayer

I want to create an MP4 that supports seeking and streaming. DASH appears to be what I want except that the segment seek points are stored in an external file (the MPD) which doesn't work for my application; I need seek metadata to be contained in the MP4.

The next closest thing seems to be fragmented MP4s with the mfra box. I think this would work but it doesn't seem well supported (mplayer and totem fail to seek, recent ffplay works). Although the primary application is streaming (with the ability to seek) I would be reluctant to give up the ability to play the video from file on "standard" players.

Is there any way I can make an MP4 that is streamable, seekable and plays within standard video players?

If I forgo the ability to play on standard video players is mfra the best way to go?

edit: By streaming I mean HTTP progressive download.

Answer (score 2):

Seeking into any MP4 file over HTTP can be done more or less simply.

If the file is not fragmented, all the seek information is located in the 'moov' box, so there is no problem. This is what [mp4box.js](http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/mp4box.js/) demonstrates. If the data is badly organized, one would have to do multiple HTTP byte-range requests. It is easier if the header boxes are first (ftyp, moov ...) and if the media data is interleaved. [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) can be used to generate such files:

```
MP4Box -add file.mp4 output.mp4
```

If the file is fragmented, indeed the seek information is spread out along the file and the 'mfra' box could be used, but it is not well supported and not reliable.

Segmentation (as used in DASH) can also be used to make HTTP seekable files, if done carefully. If you segment your file, forcing a single segment file, all the data will be in a single file (not in multiple segment files). If you add the 'sidx' box, you will have the indexing information in the file (no need for the MPD). To have both, you can segment your file using the DASH ondemand profile with MP4Box:

```
MP4Box -dash 1000 -profile ondemand file.mp4
```